Trigger to update number of volunteer
I am writing a trigger to update the number of volunteers when the minimum need for each skill has been changed.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_number_of_volunteers()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    original_total_minimal_need INT;
    new_total_minimal_need INT;
    original_volunteers_needed INT;
BEGIN
    -- Calculate the original total minimal need for the request:
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(min_need), 0) INTO original_total_minimal_need
    FROM request_skill
    WHERE request_id = OLD.request_id;

    -- Calculate the new total minimal need for the request:
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(min_need), 0) INTO new_total_minimal_need
    FROM request_skill
    WHERE request_id = NEW.request_id;

    -- Get the current total number of volunteers needed for the request:
    SELECT number_of_volunteers INTO original_volunteers_needed
    FROM request
    WHERE id = NEW.request_id;

    -- Update the request with the new total number of volunteers needed:
    UPDATE request
    SET number_of_volunteers = (original_volunteers_needed - original_total_minimal_need) + new_total_minimal_need
    WHERE id = NEW.request_id;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_number_of_volunteers_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF min_need ON request_skill
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_number_of_volunteers();

The new number_of_volunteers = (the original number_of_volunteers - the original total_minimal_need) + the new total_minimal_need
Currently, the trigger is substracting the original number_of_volunteers by the new total_minimal_need instead of the old one. Appreciate if you can advise further.

I want the trigger to substract the orginal number_of_volunteers by the  original_total_minimal_need and then plus the new_total_minimum_need (after update to new number) Currently it is substracting the new original_num_of_volunteers by the new total_minimal_need. In general the trigger does not work as expected
